# Insert array into Postgres array using PHP prepared statement

Tags: php, postgresql

I know there have been similar questions but I just can’t get this to work.

I  have a Postgres database with a of type `int[]`.  I'm using a prepared statement to do my insert.  I keep getting this error:

> "
> \n**Warning**:  pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "}"[1, 0, 0, 0]"]"\nDETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information. "

Here is how I'm doing my array:

```
$aeidarr = array();
if (isset($_POST['aeid'])){
    $aeid[] = $_POST['aeid'];
    foreach ($aeid as $aevalue){
        array_push($aeidarr, $aevalue);
    }
} else{
    array_push($aeidarr, -1);
}
```

Here is my prepared statement:

```
$insertentranceoptionsprep = pg_prepare($conn, 'insert_entranceoptions', "insert into entrances_options(uacctid, eid, aeid, eoautodoor) values ($1,$2,$3,$4);");
$insertentranceoptionsex = pg_execute($conn, 'insert_entranceoptions', array($acctid, $eid, $aeidarr, $eoautodoor));
```

I'm sure I am doing something dumb.  But I would appreciate any help.

Comment: did you mean to use single quotes for your prepare statement?

Comment: @Jack I slip up and do that sometimes but I don’t think that is the issue

Comment: It's better to use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) than the low-level Postgres driver layer of PHP.

Comment: @tadman yes, but I'm assuming there is a way to do this.

Comment: You need to escape things as Postgres wants them. Most higher-level drivers have Postgres-specific escapers for `ARRAY`, `HSTORE` and `JSON`/`JSONB` fields. If the driver doesn't do it, it's on you.